# What factors do determine the size of the core dump on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, ubuntu-16.04, coredump, crash-dumps

Post instrumenting a source tree with an LLVM pass, I am experiencing crash with core dump of arbitrarily large size. On my SSD equipped laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 x86-64, the core dump grows to ~40GB in several seconds; thus choking my hard disk space. Every time, I need to kill the process to prevent the core file grow any larger. What factors might make the core dump grow so large?

Comment: On Windows it would be the amount of RAM. I doubt you have 40 GB RAM in your laptop, though...

Comment: I have 32GB RAM installed. I doubt it has correlation with the amount o physical RAM installed.